# Optional @ObservableObject in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

I want to have an optional @ObservedObject in SwiftUI but I keep getting a compile time error of.

```sh
Property type 'AModel?' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'
```

Here is some minimum reproducible code.

```swift
import SwiftUI

public struct AView: View {
    
    //MARK: View Model
    //Error thrown here.
    @ObservedObject var model: AModel?
    
    //MARK: Body
    public var body: some View {
        Text("\(model?.value ?? 0)")
    }
    
    //MARK: Init
    public init() {
        
    }
    
}

class AModel: ObservableObject {
    let value: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Why not making `value` optional in **AModel**, that would be more doable thing!

Comment: I'm currently refactoring that way but I'd still like to know why this does not seem to work?

Comment: I know what you trying to do, And I guess you want have multi option on your custom View wether you have a model or not(nil), if is that what you want, we can solve the issue in other way.

Comment: `Optional` is an enum - not a class, so it cannot conform to `ObservableObject`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The technical reason is that `Optional` is not a class, so it cannot be conformed to `ObservableObject`.

But if you want to avoid refactoring the object itself - for example, if it's not in your control - you could do something like this:

```
struct AView: View {

    private struct Content: View {
       @ObservedObject var model: AModel
       var body: some View {
          Text("\(model.value)")
       }
    }

    var model: AModel?
    
    var body: some View {
       if let model = model {
          Content(model: model)
       } else {
          Text("0")
       }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You actually want your `init` argument to be [optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional), not the struct property.
In your case I would simply do:

```swift
import SwiftUI

public struct AView: View {
    
    //MARK: View Model
    @ObservedObject var model: AModel
    
    //MARK: Body
    public var body: some View {
        Text("\(model.value)")
    }
    
    //MARK: Init
    public init(model: AModel? = nil) {
        self.model = model ?? AModel()
    }
    
}

class AModel: ObservableObject {
    let value: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment now supports Observable, while retaining the ability to remain nil-able. Still, having a nil-value here at run-time is still considered an incorrect state in most cases, so you're just trading in a run-time crash for a non-crashing bug.